# Numerical Integration with Riemann Sum (Python)

Tags: python, return, integration

I have the following code but when it is run, it gives `0.0`
It should return a value of `2` since I am attempting to integrate `sin(x)` in the interval `[0, pi]`. 
Please advise.

```
from math import sin, pi

def Rsum(a,b):
    for i in range(1001):
        s = 0
        delx = float((b-a)/1000)
        g = i*delx
        h = (i+1)*delx

        y_i = float(sin(a+g))
        y_ii = float(sin(a+h))
        s += 1/2 * (y_i + y_ii) * delx

    return s

print Rsum(0,pi)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1/2` is `0` in python 2.x.  It is performing integer division and rounding down.  You can get what you want by using `0.5` or `1.0/2` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Of course, rookie mistake. :)

Using this, I get an answer (-4.93479408312e-06). However, this is not what is expected. The function is supposed to use the trapezoid rule to calculate the area under a curve, which in this case is sin(x).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try moving the `s = 0` outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks recursive! This works now. :)
I get 1.99999342027

However, how did this help exactly? In the previous case, was 's' being redefined (reset to 0) every time the loop was run?

Comment: @user2589188: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from math import sin, pi

def Rsum(a,b):

    for i in range(1001):
        s = 0.0
        delx = float(b-a)/1000.0
        g = i*delx
        h = (i+1.0)*delx

        y_i = float(sin(a+g))
        y_ii = float(sin(a+h))
        s += 1.0/2.0 * (y_i + y_ii) * delx
        #s += 1/2 * (sin(a+i*delx) + sin(a+(i+1)*delx)) * delx

    return s

print Rsum(0,pi)
```

You should be careful about using integer values in floating point equations, if you have an integer, then convert it with `float()`. If you have a constant in your code like `10` then make it decimal... `10.0`.

Comment: Thanks. Of course, rookie mistake. :)

Using this, I get an answer (-4.93479408312e-06). However, this is not what is expected. The function is supposed to use the trapezoid rule to calculate the area under a curve, which in this case is sin(x).

Any suggestions?