# Riemann sum in python

Tags: python, integration

I need help coding a program that will use the Riemann definition (left AND right rules) to calculate the integral of `f(x)=sin(x)` from `a=0` to `b=2*pi`. I can do this by hand for days, but I have zero idea how to code it with python.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?  Code examples?

Comment: If you can do it by hand, take every single step you do and convert that to python code.

Comment: Did you see this question? It looks very similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687756/numerical-integration-with-riemann-sum-python

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at this code: http://statmath.org/calculate_area.pdf

```
# Calcuate the area under a curve
#
# Example Function y = x^2
#
# This program integrates the function from x1 to x2
# x2 must be greater than x1, otherwise the program will print an error message.
#
x1 = float(input('x1='))
x2 = float (input('x2='))
if x1 > x2:
print('The calculated area will be negative')
# Compute delta_x for the integration interval
#
delta_x = ((x2-x1)/1000)
j = abs ((x2-x1)/delta_x)
i = int (j)
print('i =', i)
# initialize
n=0
A= 0.0
x = x1
# Begin Numerical Integration
while n < i:
delta_A = x**2 * delta_x
x = x + delta_x
A = A + delta_A
n = n+1
print('Area Under the Curve =', A)
```

Comment: This makes what I need to do more clear. I will just have to create one loop for each method (left and right).

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, looking at the equations from wiki has helped me with translating into python. Here are a few wiki pages:

[Riemann definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral)

[Fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

[Numerical integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration)

Also, The math module of python will help you with this:

[Python Math](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html)

After checking these out, look at some examples of other mathematical equations in the python language to understand how to integrate some of the math functions.